# Usage of _super for _setOption Seems Inconsistent With Documentation?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I believe that I have found a bug in the new `_super` method of jQuery UI 1.9.x but wanted to run it by you guys first before I reported it. I figure it will be an easy vote for someone out there.

Here's the ticket that I was going to submit. It details the bug:

> According to the documentation, _super() takes no arguments. However,
>   this doesn't work as expected when used in _setOption():
>   http://jsfiddle.net/grinn/8jKk8/1/
>
> As you can see by clicking the Change Text button, the value of the
>   text option is not updated even though _super was called properly,
>   according to the docs at
>   http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_super
>
> But, if you pass key and value to _super, it does work properly:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/grinn/8jKk8/2/
>
> I discovered this work-around by viewing the use of _super in the
>   jQuery UI code, itself.
>
> I'm submitting this as a bug and not a documentation issue because it
>   would seem _super is expected to work as the documentation states.
>
> Tested in Firefox 17, Chrome 23, and IE 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to report this issue. Judging from the fact that inside jQuery UI they use it as I've described below, I'm thinking that the documentation is just a little vague. For those of you experiencing this same issue, the correct way to use _super appears to be to pass through your arguments, like:

```
    _setOption: function (key, value) {
        // Your code goes here...
        this._super(key, value);
    }
```

...or more generically:

```
    _setOption: function (key, value) {
        // Your code goes here...
        this._superApply(arguments);
    }
```